# How To Kill Or CTRL+C Process In Linux Using Bash Script?

Tags: php, linux

I have a bash script to auto reconnect broadcast files once every 1 minute with a cronjob. And the bash script is running successfully.

I want every reconnection (every 1 minute) only 1 bash script is running, the previous bash script must be stopped (killed).

How do I kill or ctrl+c using a bash script when a bash script is reconect?

this is my code:

```
<?php

$address='xxx.xx.2.xx';
$port = 'xxxx';

// Send Broadcast when HQ sockcet active
if (isset($port) && ($socket=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP))
 && (socket_connect($socket, $address, $port)))  {

$text="Echo Test successful on IP $address, port $port";

//Auto Running Broadcast From HQ when Server Active
$old_path = getcwd();
chdir('/app/Extendedmodule/Socket/cli/');
@$output = shell_exec('./broadcastHq.sh');
chdir($old_path);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

socket_close($socket);
}else{
$noConnect="Enable Connect To HQ on IP $address, port $port";
echo "<pre>$noConnect</pre>";
}
?>
```

MY Bash Script :

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup /usr/local/zend/bin/php-cli /app/Extendedmodule/Socket/cli/broadcastFrom_Hq.php &
```

Comment: [`kill`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) or [`killall`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/killall.1.html)

Comment: on the server there are many processes running. Is it possible to kill specific running, so that other processes are still running?

Comment: yes, and that's is the difference between `kill` & `killall`, the `kill` command is about `kill PID` so if you want to kill specific process using it's id, `killall` command is about `killall SERVICE_NAME`

Comment: what if we don't know the PID of the process. Because everything runs automatically by the system

Comment: you can kill all previous process from the same program and then run the new one, or you will need to cache the PID once you are run the new process.

Comment: i want to kill previous process from the same program and then run the new one. the problem is whether this method can kill the previous process whose program is not the same?

Comment: killall will kill all, you need to cache the required PID to be able to kill it

Comment: Maybe you could use something like `ps -A | grep your_program | head -1 | awk '{print $1;}'` to get the pid?